# Java: Strange OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, linked-list, do-while

```
        do{

        System.out.println("inside do");
        for (int i = 0; i < i2; i++) {

             String s2 = m_area.m_items.get(i).returnName();
             if (s2.contains(s)) {

                itemexist_check = true;
                player.addItem(m_area.m_items.get(i));
                m_area.m_items.remove(i);
                } else {

                 //do nothing
             }
         }
         itemexist_check = true;
        }while(itemexist_check == false);
```

When this do statement is run, it will happily perform the "player.addItem(m_area.m_items.get(i))", but when it gets to "m_area.m_items.remove(i)"      (m_items is a LinkedList)     , it throws an "OutOfBoundsException: Index 1, Size 1". Via printing the size of the LinkedList, as well as printing the value of "i", I have determined that prior to the "m_area.m_items.remove(i)", the size of the LinkedList is 2, and the value of "i" is 0. I understood why it threw the exception. There is obviously no Element 0 in the LinkedList. What I don't know is, why didn't it throw the exception on the "player.addItem(m_area.m_items.get(i))"? Something isn't right here, please help.

Thank you

Comment: oh. apparently LinkedList.get only throws the exception when the index is less than 0, while LinkedList.remove throws the exception when the index is equal to 0. I guess my real question is, how can I fix my code?

Comment: Your question is unclear. For ex. what does `i2` point to?

Comment: Incorrect. [LinkedList.get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get%28int%29) throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`

Comment: As a sidenote: why did you wrap the whole thing in a `do while` loop? It would seem it will always exit due to that last statement setting `itemexist_check` to true. Unless you 'anonymized' this code and removed some other code, it's no use making this code more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. Why does the for loop has to be inside the do-while. Why do you have to remove the m_item you add to the player? Why don't you use an enhanced for-loop and instead you meddle with the indices?

Comment: @Efthymis: you can't modify the list you're iterating over with a for-each loop. Try it, it will just throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Yes, I do know that, but it is unclear whether the selected item had to be removed from the list. Thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The savest way to deal with list traversal + removal is to separate the two. Hence, iterate through your list using a standard forearch loop (also much easier and faster than `get` calls). Instead of removing the item, add it to a separate list and after your loop use `m_area.m_items.removeAll(removedElementsList)`.

Answer (score 2):

Is I2 the size of the list?  Then you are staying in the loop one iteration too many.  You're continuation condition should be i < i2-1.

And no, remove() does not throw an exception when index is 0, only when it's less than zero.

As for the advice to use a for-each loop, be careful.  Normally you can't modify the list within the loop -- a restriction that looks like would apply here since you are modifying m_area.m_items.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using `foreach` loop instead `for`
and for removing items save their in other set and use RemoveAll after loop

for (TypeOfListItem item : m_area.m_items) {

```
         String s2 = item.returnName();
         if (s2.contains(s)) {

            itemexist_check = true;
            player.addItem(item);
            itemsForDelete.add(item);
            } else {
             //do nothing
         }
     }
```

m_area.m_items.removeAll(itemsForDelete);